Rubber domes automatic assembly
How are silicone rubber domes accurately picked and placed onto their precise locations on a PET sheet where glue is applied in keyboard manufacturing? Are there pick-and-place machines, similar to those used for placing SMT components on PCBs, that can handle these domes?



I think often these kinds of tasks are still done manually by workers in low-income countries. But if you want to automate this, the best solution depends on the preconditions:

How many different layouts of keyboards are there (just one? multiple? very many?),
How many keyboards are being produced (hundreds/thousands/millions?),
How many different types of domes are there?

Assuming:

One type of dome,
Multiple possible keyboard layouts, and
A production size large enough to offset the investment cost,

then a possible solution could be to:

Sort the domes with a bowl feeder,
Pick and place the domes with a Scara robot or Delta robot.

If you also have multiple types of dome, then it's a trade-off between investing:

Either in multiple bowl feeders, each specific to a single type of dome, or
In one bowl feeder that can be adapted per batch to another type of dome (this implies a labour cost per change-over, as well as possibly an opportunity cost due to downtime of your production line), or
In a more advanced setup with sensors that can detect dome orientation, to only pick those domes that are oriented well. And/or also in a picker with more degrees of freedom, that can pick any dome irrespective of its orientation (e.g. similar to this application).


Thank you for the well thought answer! It's one type of rubber domes that are assembled on a single keyboard layout and possible production size of 10ku. I've looked into bowl feeders and concerned with sticking to the surface and getting deformed due to how thin and elastic those are. For pick and place, I'm exploring the options you suggested, especially something that has sensors (camera/lidar) to detect orientation and pick only correct ones.

I would not dismiss the bowl feeder option before talking to suppliers. Especially since you only have one type of dome. I expect a feeder + 3 DOF picker to be significantly lower cost,  more robust and less complex than a 5 DOF solution with 3D camera/lidar.

What do you think about using gantry-style (like SMT PnP) machines? Besides being fast and precise, they look simpler i.e. probably cheaper than robotic arms. Do you know of any of the shelf options that can be configured to work with this application?

Gantry style can for sure work, but I don't know about standard SMT pnp machines, you'd have to talk to suppliers.. Given you also mention "just one keyboard layout", I wonder if you could resort to a simple bespoke solution, e.g. drop the domes from the feeder into some sort of jig, or positioning the keyboard underneath the feeder outlet with an XY table, and dropping the domes onto the keyboard one by one straight from the feeder.

Maybe this one? https://www.fritsch-smt.de/en/automatic-pick-place/applications/assembling-of-domes

This is a very nice find! Thanks for your time, and I've accepted your answer.
